# Missing semicolon error when running SWIG on c++ header file that uses namespace std

Tags: java, c++, swig

I want to generate a wrapper file for Java from a c++ header file that uses namespace std and also includes some libraries. When I tried running swig it gives me a syntax error saying a semicolon is missing, even when my header file is from a large code base and it compiles and runs perfectly fine.

I tried including the line "using namespace std" in the .i file required by swig, and also including the libraries like    that were included in the .h file, but the same error still exists.

This is my AdaptationPlanner.h file

```cpp
// some code ...
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std; //line 68
// more code ...
```

And here is my AdaptationPlanner.i file

```
/* AdaptationPlanner.i */
%module AdaptationPlanner
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "AdaptationPlanner.h" 
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "AdaptationPlanner.h"
```

And here is the error message swig gives:

```
AdaptationPlanner.h:68: Error: Syntax error - possibly a missing semicolon.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* AdaptationPlanner.i */
%module AdaptationPlanner
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "AdaptationPlanner.h" 
using namespace std; /* <--- */
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "AdaptationPlanner.h"
```

I can't really tell why you are having an issue like that. However, care to try the above solution? Just explicitly mention the namespace in the interface file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. getchar's suggestion did not resolve it. What resolved it was renaming the %module name from "AdaptationPlanner" to "AdaptationPlannerSwig" to avoid the name collision.

Answer (score 0):

You must using -c++ in your swig command.

**Example:** `swig -java -package xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -c++ AdaptationPlanner.i`